# Is it possible Realm sorting by string date like a timestamp?

Tags: android, sorting, realm

I have some difficult task. In my database i have a field

`String date;`

this date saves like a `yyMMddHHmmss` . I need to sort a field `date` by `DESCENDING`. But this field is a String(

I made like this:

```
realm.where(Documents.class).findAll().sort("date", Sort.DESCENDING);
```

But this medhod doesnt work.

Can i create own custom sorting, it will be like this:

1. for each element i will get a string date `yyMMddHHmmss`
2. then i want to conwert a string date `yyMMddHHmmss` to timestamp date
3. sorting items by timestamp.

Is it possible?

Comment: If the date has a format like the one you have that should work because it is alphabetical sorting, "2020" can be sorted in comparison with "1979" such as "202001" in comparison with "202002"

Comment: @cutiko That is possibly true - the question states a two-digit year, in which case dates within the same century will sort OK but spanning centuries (as with your example using 1979 and 2020) will not.

Comment: @r1299597 Do you have to store in the Realm as a string? Realm supports Date types directly - you could store as a date and then your sort will work.

Comment: @ChrisShaw you are right, worst case scenario if realm date doesn't work then he could transform it to date when receiving the server response then saving a sortable string